# C# and Namespaces

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Should differentiation by namespaces be only used when there are third party libraries and be avoided to differentiate the classes we write ourselves?

In Web Api, if the controller and action names are the same but the namespaces are different, routing does not happen and 404 error is given. I found out that a custom controller selector can be used to overcome this but since the built-in selector ignores it, I wonder if this is a deliberate design decision. Is there a reason why I should avoid differentiation only by namespaces?

Comment: Yes, things named the same tend to be confused with each other (by humans).

Comment: Can you talk us through what the **benefits** of having two things (e.g. controllers) called the same thing but being in different namespaces would be @JohnL ?

Comment: In one of my first jobs, I worked at a place with 3 other Amy's.  Whenever a call would come in over the PA system, all four of us would show up at the front desk.  Eventually we gave each other nicknames (I was Scooter) to differentiate us.  Don't let this happen to your code.  Try to give things distinctive names *and* logically organize them using namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

In ASP.NET MVC/WebApi the routes are determined automatically from the `Controller`'s name. So, if there are two `Controller`s with the same name and do not override the route with a `RouteAttribute`, they share the same route.

There are two ways you can solve this problem:

1. Use `Areas`: areas are meant to separate your application into multiple MVCs, each with specific sections (commonly separated by authentication/authorization rules). This would look like:

   - Public

     - Controllers
     - Views
     - Models
   - Admin

     - Controllers
     - Views
     - Models
2. Override the `route` that the controllers use (though untested, not sure if it would work):

   ```
   [Route("MyHome")]
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
   }

   [Route("MySecondHome")]
   public class HomeController : ApiController
   {
   }
   ```

Also notice that for the `RouteAttribute` to work, you need to enable it first. You can find more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2).

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Attribute routing.
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    // Convention-based routing.
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

**However**, you should attempt not to use classes with the same name, regardless of the namespace structure. It makes it harder to recognize what exactly you are dealing with.

Comment: I think to fit with the OP's question, one of your example controllers should be an `ApiController`.  `Route` will work if attribute routing is enabled.

Comment: @Amy I had forgotten that Web Api 2 uses `ApiController` (been using ASP.NET Core for some time now). Answer updated

Comment: I expected that to be the case.  Same thing here.

Comment: You left out the option to use the `namespaces` parameter on the route, in which this is exactly the case that parameter is meant to solve. But I agree that if name collisions can be avoided altogether it would be best.

Comment: @NightOwl888 I really did not know of that option, I'll add it, thanks